# Example of adding secondary CIDR block for a subnet in Cloudformation Template

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, vpc

I'm trying to create a new public/private subnet pair in my VPC stack using Cloudformation but I don't have any IP space left, so I want to add a Secondary CIDR block to my VPC and create the new subnet from that secondary block. Are there any YAML code examples of a template that does so? I can't find one anywhere, and I'm having trouble figuring out what to add where.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly you simply want to associate another CIDR with your VPC. Full docs on that can be found -> [AWS VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-resize).

To accomplish that I believe the following YAML can lead you to a desired solution;

```
Resources:
  VPC:
   Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
   Properties:
     CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
  VpcCidrBlock:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
    CidrBlock: 192.0.0.0/16
  Subnet1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
  Subnet2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
    CidrBlock: 192.0.0.0/24

Outputs:
  VpcId:
    Value: !Ref VPC
  PrimaryCidrBlock:
    Value: !GetAtt VPC.CidrBlock
  CidrBlockAssociation:
    Value: !Select [ 0, !GetAtt VPC.CidrBlockAssociations ]
```